# Uploading file in sharepoint library throws an unhandled exception(hresult: 0x80020009, errorcode: -2147352567) with empty error message

Tags: sharepoint, file, exception, upload

I m using following code sample to upload multiple files (using sharepoint Object Model, no webservice) in a document library, but some times it throws exception hresult: 0x80020009, with error code -2147352567 and error message is empty (empty string) while file is upload successfully to the document library. And mostly it occurs only first time mean it occurs when uploading first document after that all process goes smoothly no exception occurs after first time occured. If i eat that exception it works fine. Can any one help me to trace the problem, I can't understand why it throws exception while file has been uploaded to document library. I want to know What's the actual reason and what should I do to avoid that problem.

Code:
.....

```
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(folderUrl);
foreach(.....)
{
folder.Files.Add(folderUrl + "/" + fileName, file.Data, true);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full formatted code ?

Comment: using (var site = new SPSite(folderUrl))
using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
{
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(folderUrl);
foreach (File file in fileSource.GetFiles())
{
folder.Files.Add(folderUrl + "/" + fileName, file.Data, true);
}
}

Comment: I have exactly the same problem ax Alex - has anybody found some solution?

Answer (score 1):

try using the code provided below that will  help you out

```
using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite("http://SPS01"))
        {
            using (SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                spweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPFolder spfolder = spweb.Folders[Site + "/Shared Documents/"];
                byte[] content = null;
                using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream("C:/Sample.docx", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    content = new byte[(int)filestream.Length];
                    filestream.Read(content, 0, (int)filestream.Length);
                    filestream.Close();
                }

                SPFile spfile = spfolder.Files.Add("Sample.docx", content, true);

                //Upload file in subfolder.
                //SPFile spfile = spfolder.SubFolders["Demonstration Folder"].Files.Add("Sample.docx", content, true);   
            spfile.Update(); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: still facing same problem. it throws exception at line: spfolder.Files.Add("Sample.docx", content, true);

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException was caught
  Message=""
  Source=Microsoft.SharePoint
  ErrorCode=-2147352567
  NativeErrorMessage=FAILED hr detected (hr = 0x80020009)

Comment: Check SPFileCollection for validity, my guess is that the exception is being
thrown because you're trying to call a method on an invalid object.(spfolder.Files)

Comment: Ashutosh Singh - I experience the same problem as Alex. How can I "check SPFileCollection for validity"? I've looked on SPFileCollection and related SPFolder object properties (in debugger) - they looks the same on each file upload (except files count and collection in folder of course) but SP throws an exception (native code) on the first upload.